# Access 2016 Form Control Validation Rule Not Firing

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a simple unbound access 2016 form. On the form, I have several controls including text and combo boxes. On the first text box control I would like to require a data value (underlying table field data type is short text).

I have set the Validation Rule property for the control in the property sheet to "Is Not Null" and added an appropriate validation text message.

For an unknown reason I have not been able to get this validation rule to ever fire. I have cleared the validation rule on the table to make sure it wasn't interfering, however, no luck.

It's like the validation check is not happening when focus leaves the control. There is no other event procedure that has been written that would interfere either.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As long as you don't change the control, the validation will not be triggered. I'd suggest to use the before_update event on form level to check whether your control is null or not.

Comment: Thanks Rene, I actually did not realize that the validation will not get triggered unless there is a change. In looking at the before update events, they have the same issue, it will not fire unless a change has occurred. My desire is to trigger the validation rule as the user exits the control. It looks like John Fowler may have the solution or I can always drop to the control on exit event procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement was to validate the control for a missing value using the validation rule when the control lost focus (ie user tabbed out of text box without ever entering a value). I wanted the user to get immediate feedback that they needed to provide a value for the given control.

**As Rene pointed out in the comments, the validation rule does not fire unless there has been a value change.**

The Sendkeys solution has issues, I only use Sendkeys as a last resort.

The solution in this case was to put the validation test in the Control_OnExit event handler. The user gets immediate feedback as desired and does not wait until the record is submitted.

One further note that could easily be missed; *in an unbound form, the before_update event will never fire.*

Answer (score 0):

You can give the control a default value, then

```
Form_load()
Yourcontrol.setfocus
Sendkeys "{DEL}"
```

Comment: I think I will just handle this issue in the control OnExit procedure. The Sendkeys del triggers the numlock on/off toggle, so this won't work.